# zoomToRect fails consistently for certain websites in iOS 7, but works in iOS 6 consistently

Tags: ios6, ios7, xcode5

In iOS 6 and iOS 6.1 the code below works as I expected for all websites, which is zooming in on a portion of the UIWebView somewhere close to the middle of the screen.

In iOS 7 zooming works correctly the first time, but after the first time, zooming occurs on the top left corner of the screen, which is not where the x and y coordinates of the rectangle are located (supposed to be around the middle somewhere). In certain websites zooming consistently fails with iOS 7 after the first time, while in others it works correctly every time in both iOS6 and iOS7. This problem never occurred before in iOS 6.

```
UIScrollView *myZoomView = [[myWebView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[myZoomView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(380, 490, 165, 50) animated:YES];
```